# Javascript values not updating after dropdown selection

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a value that I'm passing from the server side C# code to the client side javascript that I need to update based on a dropdown selection.  The value gets changed as required in my C# logic but the value change is never picked up by the client.

Here is my C# code setting the value

```
protected void ddlCurrency_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddlCurrencyType = (DropDownList)upFilter.FindControl("ddlCurrency");

    CurrencyId = int.Parse(ddlCurrencyType.SelectedItem.Value);
}

private void SetCurrencySymbol()
{
    if (CurrencyId == 2)
    {
        CurrencySymbol = "€";
    }
    else
    {
        CurrencySymbol = "$";
    }

}
```

And my javascript variable

```
var currencySymbol = "<%=CurrencySymbol%>";
```

The SetCurrencySymbol method is called in a `if(!Page.IsPostBack)` condition.

Here is my dropdownlist code

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlCurrency" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCurrency_OnSelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" onChange="setCurrencySymbol">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

That javascript variable needs to get set to the C# value after a new item is selected from the dropdown.  The original value from when the page loaded is retained after a new selection is made however.  Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where and how do u declare `CurrencySymbol` serverside? And where do you assign `currencySymbol` on client?

Comment: You say yourself that `SetCurrenctSymbol` is called if `!IsPostBack` so how do you propose it's set on a `PostBack`?

Comment: `CurrencySymbol` is a public property

Comment: Call `SetCurrencySymbol` in `ddlCurrency_OnSelectedIndexChanged`